# How to save the intersection points as nodes for multiple use later?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following MWE will not compile because `\n` is not recognized in `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red, smooth, name path=first] plot coordinates {(1,1)(2,3)(4,6)(5,2)(7,5)};
    \draw [blue, smooth, name path=second] plot coordinates {(1,5)(2,1)(4,3)(5,5)(7,1)};
    \path [name intersections={of=first and second, total=\n}];
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}{\draw (intersection-\i) circle [radius=3pt];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My objective is to save the intersection points as nodes for multiple use later. How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `\n` command is only defined within the scope of the current TikZ command (i.e. within the scope of the `\path` command in your example). The following fix combines your `\path` and `\foreach` commands into a single `\draw` command. It is very similar to an example given in **13.3.2 Intersections of Arbitrary Paths** of the TikZ manual.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red, smooth, name path=first] plot coordinates {(1,1)(2,3)(4,6)(5,2)(7,5)};
    \draw [blue, smooth, name path=second] plot coordinates {(1,5)(2,1)(4,3)(5,5)(7,1)};
    \draw [name intersections={of=first and second, total=\n}]  
      \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}{(intersection-\i) circle [radius=3pt]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update 1.** I understand now that you wish to save the nodes outside of the scope of a single command. Following Andrew's suggestion in the comments below, you can define the nodes using the `\coordinate` command, like this.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red, smooth, name path=first] plot coordinates {(1,1)(2,3)(4,6)(5,2)(7,5)};
    \draw [blue, smooth, name path=second] plot coordinates {(1,5)(2,1)(4,3)(5,5)(7,1)};
    \draw [name intersections={of=first and second, total=\n}]  
      \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {(intersection-\i) coordinate (red-blue-intersection-\i)};
    \draw (red-blue-intersection-1) circle [radius=3pt];
    \draw (red-blue-intersection-2) circle [radius=3pt];
    \draw (red-blue-intersection-3) circle [radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update 2.** You may also wish for `\n`, the *number* of nodes, to escape the scope. Then those three `\draw` commands in my code above can be replaced by a loop. I don't know a 'good' way to do this, but here's a hacky way that seems to work.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red, smooth, name path=first] plot coordinates {(1,1)(2,3)(4,6)(5,2)(7,5)};
    \draw [blue, smooth, name path=second] plot coordinates {(1,5)(2,1)(4,3)(5,5)(7,1)};
    \draw [execute at begin node={\global\let\n=\n}, name intersections={of=first and second, total=\n}]  
      \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {(intersection-\i) coordinate (red-blue-intersection-\i)};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
      \draw (red-blue-intersection-\i) circle [radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See my updated question.

Comment: @mozartstraße Replace `(intersection-\i) circle [radius=3pt]` by `(intersection-\i) coordinate (red-blue-intersection-\i)` or whatever naming scheme you want.

Comment: It's not ideal, but you can just put `/utils/exec={\global\let\n=\pgfintersectionsolutions}` (or `/utils/exec={\global\let\n=\n}`) after the `name intersections` key to get the same effect as update 2. Or put the global assignment inside `\pgfextra{}` after all of the options.